# How do I present homebrew material in a critique question?

Tags: discussion, homebrew, dnd-5e

I have begun working on a homebrew class for D&D 5e and I plan to ask a critique question on rpg.se once I'm finished.  I figured it would be better to ask this meta question now than at the end of the process, so I can use any advice given here to take notes as I write.

How do I show the features from a *several-page-long* class document?  Can I display them **off-site** on a **google doc** or must I display the features and tables on **RPG.se**?  When describing the reasoning and play test results for any particular feature, should I do so on se or the google doc/recommended alternative?

Additionally, should I leave out all info **not related to the features** such as lore and the quick build to lessen the reading? I'm assuming anything not completely feature related is only import on a per-question basis, but is their any information/lore that isn't?

Comment: Related: [Are “is this balanced” questions on-topic?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7952/33569), [Are we satisfied with the state of homebrew review questions?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9096/33569), [How can I ask a good homebrew review question?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8121/33569), [How should I ask about my D&D 5e Homebrew being balanced?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8171/33569), [How do I ask a good character build/optimization question for D&D 5e?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8123/33569)

Comment: To clarify for anyone just seeing this question for the first time now, this question was originally very broad as in encompassed several questions regarding homebrew critique.  Because of the above conversations, I narrowed the 'all-encompassing' question down to this current iteration.

Comment: Now that the question has been edited, I've cleaned up the other comments and [moved them to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94839/discussion-on-question-by-robotex-how-do-i-present-homebrew-material-in-a-critiq).

Answer (score 3):

## All information Relevant to the Question Should be on Stack Exchange.

Information necessary for the question, such as the actual details of the class, should be in the post and not a linked document, for a couple reasons:

- You may delete the linked document at some point in the future, this would make the question be unable to be understood by future Stackizens.
- You may want to change the information in the document based on the answers given. This would go against our [Homebrew-Review](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8121/) policy, as it would cause the answers to be out of context when read in the future.

This means that all information pertinent to answering the question should be viewable in the question, so that if someone in 20 years were to come across the question, it and the answers would make sense in the context of the post.

Linking to documents for other information, such as a sample build, that would not be pertinent to the question would be acceptable as links or in a list of additional resources provided in the question itself.

Comment: Just to add; for readability it is very useful to put the text into blockquotes (>) to help distinguish the material from question/context/commentary.