# Mounted archer/caster question should be reopened

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions

[What's the best build for a mounted archer/caster?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/152676/4563) was closed as Primarily Opinion-Based. It is not. It is something on which experts can vet the quality of a given suggestion and vote accordingly; it is not purely about preference. There are good ways, and bad ways, to accomplish this concept. And, as an expert in the system in question, there are limited enough good ways to do it that Too Broad also does not apply.

[This meta question directly addresses, and approves of, questions of this sort.](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1641/8610) We have numerous successful examples of questions of this form answered well here. Two of the reopen votes (per comments) come from users with substantial experience answering such questions (well, if I do say so myself). Some of the original close votes were put on the question prior to a system tag being added, which was completely correct but not clear or visible once five votes had been accrued. It’s impossible (for me, anyway) to tell when votes came in relative to the system tag being added, but at least 3 were (since the final close reason was Primarily Opinion-Based, not Unclear as a lack of system tag would indicate), and only one of those who voted to close the question has experience with this sort of question.

So this question is to draw attention to this question and spur the reopen votes it deserves.

Comment: Not sure we need a meta on this...it was closed and votes have been/are coming in to reopen. There is no open/close cycle.

Comment: @NautArch It’s stalled at 3 reopen votes for a full day; meta discussions of particular closed questions is one of the most common and important uses of Meta on SE network-wide (though oddly underused here). I see a question that can be answered, a user who can be helped, who isn’t getting help, and I want to fix that. Also, this is part of a broader trend I feel like I’m seeing where it seems like any question asking for any kind of judgment on the answerer’s parts is drawing close votes, when that judgment is one of the most valuable things we offer.

Comment: Do you have the capability to view individual votes instead of just the aggregate reason, or is that restricted to diamond mods? Because, not gonna lie, I'm feeling pretty unfairly called out by this.

Comment: My vote was your standard "unclear until system tagged".

Comment: @sevenbrokenbricks Aaaah, fair enough—I could not see when you voted or what reason you chose, and I didn’t realize that had been missing. You were completely correct then, and I apologize for my assumptions. I will amend the question with that data, which is even more pertinent here. My apologies again, I was also doing the best I could with the data available to me, and—and I apologize again, because it *should* have—it didn’t cross my mind to consider something like that.

Comment: @sevenbrokenbricks Fixed, and my apologies again.

Comment: Thank you, that does mean a lot.

Comment: I voted to close as unclear, not because of a lack of system tag, but because of a lack of allowed sources and goals. And I stand by it.

Comment: @Miniman Well, your votes are yours to cast, but that flies in the face of the established meta discussion as well as in the face of our general experience with these questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Thanks to the community working together ...

... it's open again. Teamwork for the win!

This answer is provided [as requested here](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9310/mounted-archer-caster-question-should-be-reopened#comment30459_9311).