# Drow wizard with Wild Talent question

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions

[This question about a drow wizard who received the Wild Talent feat](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/156377/4563) was closed as Too Broad. It should not have been.

Per [this meta discussion](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1641/4563), questions like this are supported here, and we have dozens of successful examples. This questions lays out exactly what levels the character already has, as well as the sources available. It’s a general question with a fair amount of detail. “Too Broad” isn't even close. A good answer can easily discuss the usage of the Wild Talent feat and the pros and cons of trying to multiclass into a psionic class.

It is possible that this question garnered more close votes than it otherwise would have due to the relatively poor grammar and spelling in the original iteration of the question. I would suggest to any such close-voters that they might, instead, do some simple copy-editing rather than closing down the question.

Comment: Not only could it have attracted a definite Answer, it would have - I was working on one when the question was closed, so when I tried to post it, I saw the "The question has been closed" banner at the top of the screen. Fortunately, I managed to save a copy of it onto my computer locally.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The question's been reopened now.